How to check why my GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY is not properly loaded?
I am running a CircleCI pipeline that fails
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Could not read json file /home/circleci/gcloud-service-key.json: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I added in my project env variables

by copying values
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n.....END PRIVATE KEY-----\n

1736 characters
How to doublecheck that I made a mistake?
Do I need base 64 decode in my line?

A Service Account key is a JSON-formatted string. See the instructions specifically step #2 Create and storage a service account
